# Ajax with jQuery in Laravel error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to implement a dependent select boxes in Laravel using ajax with jQuery .By dependent I mean cell and department table are related by many to one relation. After selecting department, other select box should get populated by cells in that department.

I have defined route set as

`Route::post('/admin/routing_setting/get_cells/', 'AdminController@get_cells');`

`get_cells` function is

```
 $cells = App\Cell::where('department_id', $request->department_id)->get();
        return View('ajax.get_cell_from_dept')->with(compact('cells'));
```

Script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  // load() functions
  var loadUrl = "{{ url('/admin/routing_setting/get_cells/') }}";
  var htmldata = $("#dept_select").val();
  var op = "";

  $("#dept_select").on('change', function(e) {
    /*$("#cell_select").load(loadUrl, {department_id: htmldata});*/

      var div = $(this).parent();  
      var dept_id = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: loadUrl,
          data: {'department_id': dept_id },
          success:function(data){
              op = data;
              div.find("#cell_select").append(op);
              console.log("hii " + op);
          }
      });
    });
});
```

`#dept_select` is id for department select box. `#cell_select` is id for cell select box. I have not included html code. I will post if needed.

Above code gives me error in console as follows:

```
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6 POST http://localhost/pms/public/admin/routing_setting/get_cells 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: have you checked the url by just returning a simple hi from the route?

Comment: have you tried to print the request->department_id??

Comment: It's error 500 not 404 witch means there some error in your logic on the server side ! look at the log and see if there is some logged errors

Comment: Error 500 is not the same as a 404, take a look in the network tab of your inspector and post the error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code from `div.find("#cell_select").append(op);` to  `$("#cell_select").append(op);` . It worked.